# OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to learn how to use sockets in python to communicate between two computers. Unfortunately I get this error when everything seem to be right:

> OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Upon googling, I found that this is because the connection may have dropped. But I run both the client and server side of the program in the same machine itself. I tried connecting again from the client end and I get this:

> OSError: [Errno 106] Transport endpoint is already connected

indicating that the previous connection is still intact. I am pretty confused as to what is happening and how to make it work. Here is a screenscreen shot which shows what I am trying to do and the problem:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I tested your code with a little change on python 3.5.0 and it works:
I think the trick is in `sock.accept()` method which returns a tuple:

> **socket.accept()**   Accept a connection. The socket must be bound to an
>   address and listening for connections. The **return value is a pair**
>   (conn, address) where conn is a new socket object usable to send and
>   receive data on the connection, and address is the address bound to
>   the socket on the other end of the connection.

## server

```
#server
>>> import socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.bind(("localhost", 8081))
>>> sock.listen(2)
>>> conn, addr = sock.accept()
>>> data= conn.recv(1024).decode("ascii")
```

## client:

```
#client
>>> import socket
>>> sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> sock.connect(("localhost",8081))
>>> sock.send("hi".encode())
2
>>> sock.send("hiiiiiii".encode())
8
>>> sock.send(("#"*1020).encode())
1020
```

Answer (score 5):

I've been getting the same error, and I realized that it's because of one small issue: In the `handle_client` function, I put `server.recv` instead of `conn.recv`, so the `server.py` program was trying to receive data from its own side.

Below is the corrected version:

`server.py`:

```
import socket
import threading

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    while True:
        msg_length = conn.recv(64).decode("utf-8") # I got the error when I put server.recv
        if msg_length:
           msg = conn.recv(int(msg_length)).decode('utf-8') # Here too
           print(msg)

def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 5050))

start()
```

`client.py`:

```
import socket
import threading

def send(msg):
    client.send(str(len(msg)).encode('utf-8').ljust(64))
    client.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 5050))

send("Hello world!")
```