# Simple socket error : OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, pickle

I am trying to remake some old, really bad code that I wrote. In that code it had functionality to send data to be stored on a server, it's been a long time since I have worked with sockets and I can't figure out why I am getting this error

Server side:

```
import socket
import threading
import pickle

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    print("listening")
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    with clientsocket:
        print("receiving data")
        data = s.recv(1024)
        findata = pickle.loads(data)
        print(findata)
        if not data:
            break
        with open("pscore.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(findata, f)
            s.send("done".encode())
```

Client side:

```
def serversave():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 1234))
    scores = {"test" : 5}
    serial = pickle.dumps(scores)
    s.send(serial)
    s.recv(1024).decode()
```

After I run them the server returns

```
╰─ python3 server.py
listening
receiving data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 28, in <module>
    data = s.recv(1024)
OSError: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

and the client returns:

```
python3 client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 36, in <module>
    serversave()
  File "client.py", line 27, in serversave
    s.recv(1024).decode()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249188/oserror-errno-107-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: \[Errno 107\] Transport endpoint is not connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249188/oserror-errno-107-transport-endpoint-is-not-connected)